# Dune "official" artwork

Tags: dune, art

I would like to know if there is some Dune-related comprehensive artwork (not including live-action stuff) officially endorsed by Frank or Brian Herbert. The scans on Internet of Osmius and Erasmus from the cover books are simply pitiful in size. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

John Schoenherr drew the pictures for an official version of the first book called *The Illustrated Dune*, which was published in 1978 with Frank's approval. It's out of print, but can be found on second-hand sites - I have a copy, and it's beautiful. You can see scans of some of the pictures [here](http://ski-ffy.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/illustrated-dune.html).

Answer (score 4):

There is a Frank Herbert book titled Eye published in 1985 ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(Frank_Herbert)) [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425083985)) Within this book was a short illustrated story titled *The Road to Dune* (not to be confused with the novel) ([dune wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/The_Road_to_Dune_(short_story))).

The story contained a number of full page drawings that accompanied it.

From [Dune Wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/File:Ornithopter-RoadtoDune.jpg) an example of part of one image:

[image: Sample of one image]

Other images from this short story can be seen in various Wikipedia pages:

- [Temple of Alia on Arrakis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Temple_of_Alia_from_The_Road_to_Dune.jpg)
- [Grand Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GrandPalace%2BDunes.jpg)
- [Princess Irulan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Irulan-RoadtoDune.jpg)
- [Duncan Idaho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DuncanIdaho-RoadtoDune.jpg)
- [Bene Gesserit Reverend Mother Gaius Helen Mohiam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mohiam-RoadtoDune.jpg)

Do realize that this is a rather short short story with most of the pages dedicated to the artwork, and it isn't that many pages of artwork either.  However, it is wonderful quality images and part of the Dune canon.